# Javascript - Mapping over an object, changing key/values in the object and pushing to new object

Tags: javascript, typescript, object

I am having trouble with accessing the keys/values/entries in an object (array), slightly changing that object and pushing it to a new empty object (newArray). I can access the keys, values & entries but cannot change them.

The code below works fine but I would like to make it less specific and more generic so I can use this function elsewhere too.

I have tried using Object.keys(), Object.values() and Object.entries(), along with keyof typeof x but to no avail as .replace() won't work on the object.

The object is downloaded as a CSV and I use double quotes to separate fields as fields may contain commas and will throw the CSV fields off if kept in.

```
let array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;

let newArray = [];

array.forEach(s => {
    let x = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(s)); 
    x.addressLine1 = x.addressLine1.replace(x.addressLine1, `"${x.addressLine1}"`);
    x.addressLine2 = x.addressLine2 ? x.addressLine2.replace(x.addressLine2, `"${x.addressLine2}"`) : '';
    x.town = x.town.replace(x.town, `"${x.town}"`);
    x.postcode = x.postcode.replace(x.postcode, `"${x.postcode}"`);
    newArray.push(x);
});
```

Attempt with keyof typeof:

```
array.forEach(s => {
    let x = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(s));
    let property: keyof typeof x;
    for (property in x) {
        property = property ? property.replace(property, `"${property}"`) : '';
    newArray.push(x);
```

Object should look like this:

```
{
    "addressLine1": "\"The Road\"",
    "addressLine2": "",
    "town": "\"London\"",
    "postcode": "\"SE1 5QH\"",
}
```

Comment: How does your object look like? How do you want the new one to look like?

Comment: What's the input, what the expected output? Why do you want to wrap every value with quotes although they are already strings? Where's the `Object,keys()`, or `.values()` or `.entries()` attempt?

Comment: Why is this tagged with `angular` and `typescript`?  Nothing in your example is related to these tags.

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? All this parsing and serializing, back and forth and wrapping of strings in `""`. This looks evil.

Comment: I have added an example object. It will be downloaded as a CSV and I use double quotes to separate fields as fields may contain commas, which throws the fields off. I have removed the Angular tag.

Comment: how are you generating the CSV? you should add the quotes on serializing as CSV, not add them to your "data objects". ideally your CSV generator should have an option for that.

Comment: Why `let property: keyof typeof x;`? That's the only, useless, TypeScript thing in your question.

Comment: `property ? ... : ...` will always execute the truthy path (unless you have a column without a name and that is stored with an empty string as the key in the object)

Answer (score -1):

You could try not to "stringify" your objects and make it directly from the object.

Maybe something like this (I leave you a working example in here):
https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-dawn-w85z3

```
let objArray = [
  {
    addressLine1: "anothernamefieldexampleline1",
    addressLine2: "exampleline2",
    town: "exampletown1",
    postcode: "examplepostcode1"
  },
  {
    addressLine1: "exampleline1b",
    addressLine2: "exampleline2b",
    town: "exampletown1b",
    postcode: "examplepostcodeb"
  }
];
let array = typeof objArray != "object" ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;

let newArray = array.map((_itemObject) => {

  let returnObject={};


  let arrayKeyProperties = [];
  for (const key in _itemObject) {
    arrayKeyProperties.push(key);
  };

  console.log(arrayKeyProperties);

  arrayKeyProperties.forEach(
    (_prop) => returnObject[_itemObject[_prop]] = _itemObject[_prop]
  );

  return returnObject;
});

console.log(newArray);
```

I show image of output, with the created array with new objects with new field names (based on the value of the old ones).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, however I am trying to avoid mentioning specific keys as I want to be able to use this elsewhere and use Object.keys(array) as an example so it loops through all keys of that Object, without me specifically mentioning each one.

Comment: ok, I didn't get it well. I edited my previous answer to solve your problem. Try it with the new way (for generic keys) and comment please.